# Juniper SRX - interface filters vs firewall rules?

Tags: juniper-junos, juniper-srx

I'm trying to display all firewall rule associated with a specific interface. However, the best I can find is `show interfaces filters`. I'm assuming since these are called "filters", they're not the same as the "rules" from `show security application-firewall rule-sets all`...

Could someone enlighten me here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, these are not the same thing.

**"Interface Filters" / Firewall Filters**

The `show interfaces filters` command is used to show what **firewall filters** are applied to each interface, and in which direction.  Firewall filters are supported on just about every Juniper hardware platform.

```
jhead@MX-WS-ZT-1> show interfaces filters ge-0/0/0
Interface       Admin Link Proto Input Filter         Output Filter
ge-0/0/0        up    up
ge-0/0/0.0      up    up   inet  MGMT
```

In a general sense, firewall filters are far less robust than the application firewall feature.  They cannot do deep packet inspection (they operate on Layers 3 and 4), they can see things like source/destination IP or source/destination port.  The most common use for firewall filters is to protect your control/management plane on a Juniper device, here's a very basic example on how to only allow SSH.

**NOTE:** Firewall filters are generally called ACL's by other vendors and the industry.

**NOTE:** Firewall filters can also be used in CoS configuration.

```
jhead@SRX1> show configuration firewall
    family inet {
        filter MGMT {
            term SSH {
                from {
                    port 22;
                }
                then accept;
            }
        }
    }

jhead@SRX1> show configuration interfaces ge-0/0/0
unit 0 {
    family inet {
        filter {
            input MGMT;
        }
        address 172.16.67.2/24;
    }
}
```

If you want some good information, check out the [Juniper Documentation](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos13.1/information-products/pathway-pages/config-guide-firewall-filter/config-guide-firewall-filter.html).

**Application Firewall**

The other command you referenced, `show security application-firewall rule-sets all` relates to SRX's application firewall feature.

The full feature set of application firewalls can get pretty unwieldy, but in short they do a much more thorough analysis of the traffic.  If you check out the [Application Firewall Overview](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos12.1/topics/concept/application-firewall-overview.html) you'll see the following text:

> Many dynamic applications use HTTP static ports to tunnel non-HTTP
>   traffic through the network. Such applications can send traffic that
>   might not be adequately controlled by standard network firewall
>   policies, leading to a security threat. **Standard policies function
>   based on IP address and port and therefore are not effective with
>   these dynamic applications.**

The reference to "standard network firewall policies" is pretty much a direct comparison to the above mentioned "firewall filters".  Let me know if this isn't clear, and I'll happily edit my answer.

Comment: Excellent, thanks - especially for the docs, this will help. Is there a walk-through somewhere of setting up example firewall rules and seeing which rules are in place on your device / per interface? Can you apply rules per interface (I assume this has to be _yes_)?